# SSMS SSIS Execution Reports Not Loading

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssms

I recently lost the ability to run execution reports on all SSIS packages in SSMS. In addition to this I am no longer able to run SSIS packages in Visual Studio. I have reinstalled SSMS to a more recent version (19.1) and updated my .NET based off other recommendations on the internet, none of these fixed/changed the issue. The error message I get in SSMS when running an execution report is as follows:

> Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly '35840 bytes loaded from Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000003 (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common)

The full error is:

```
An error occurred during local report processing. (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports.Report.InitializeReportControl(ReportViewer reportControl)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports.ReportToolWindow.RenderReport(Report report, LocalReport localReport)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports.ReportsManager.CreateReportWindow(Report report)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports.ReportsManager.ShowReport(ReportInfo reportInfo, ReportContext reportContext, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean addToMru)

===================================

Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly '35840 bytes loaded from Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000003 (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.ProcessLoadingExprHostException(ObjectType assemblyHolderObjectType, Exception e, ProcessingErrorCode errorCode)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.LoadCompiledCode(IExpressionHostAssemblyHolder expressionHostAssemblyHolder, Boolean includeParameters, Boolean parametersOnly, ObjectModelImpl reportObjectModel, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext..ctor(ProcessingContext originalProcessingContext, Report report, ErrorContext errorContext, DateTime executionTime, Boolean snapshotProcessing, IConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.ProcessReportParameters(DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, Boolean isSnapshot, Boolean& needsUpgrade)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.ProcessAndStoreReportParameters(ParameterInfoCollection newParameters)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.SetReportParameters(NameValueCollection userSpecifiedValues)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
```

The error itself and what I'm doing to trigger it:

[image: Error Message]

[image: Error Trigger]

Comment: What does reporting services have to do with this if it's SSIS you're having problems with? Also SSMS 2019 doesn't exist; do you mean SSMS *19* (which was released in 2022)?

Comment: Hi Thom, I assume with it mentioning ReportViewer that it's somehow related but as I said, I know nothing about the inner workings of all this. And yes sorry it is V19.1.

Comment: Well, you aren't the first to encounter this error message. It was also asked in [Any idea why we getting an error viewing an Integration Services Catalog standard report in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76765627), but that question has been deleted without a satisfactory answer being given. (It's still in Google's search cache.)